# Registering DynaCaches with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector, dynacache

Hi I am attempting to use [Dynacache](http://dynacache.codeplex.com/) in my solution to cache data I am returning from Database so when I use Telerik grid to filter the data page etc I dont have to go back to the DB to get the data each time.

The example on the DynaCache page shows it being used with Ninject DI as below:

```
kernel.Bind<IDynaCacheService>().To<MemoryCacheService>();
kernel.Bind<ITestClass>().To(Cacheable.CreateType<TestClass>());
```

I am using [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/) as my DI container.  Has anyone used Dynacache with SimpleInjector as I am having some difficulty in getting the correct syntax to Register Dynacache with SimpleInjector the same way it is shown in Ninject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a [blog post](http://www.goatly.net/using-dynacache-with-simpleinjector) covering this now - the answer marked as correct isn't actually right - MemoryCacheService needs to be a singleton because it contains a MemoryCache instance that needs to be shared across all dependent instances.

Answer (score 2):

The Simple Injector equivalent is:

```
container.Register<IDynaCacheService, MemoryCacheService>();
container.Register(typeof(ITestClass), Cacheable.CreateType<TestClass>());
```

However, since `MemoryCacheService` is a framework type, you'd be better (as explained [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97)) of making the registration using a factory delegate:

```
container.Register<IDynaCacheService>(() => new MemoryCacheService());
container.Register(typeof(ITestClass), Cacheable.CreateType<TestClass>());
```