# Dynacache doesn't cache data

Tags: c#, .net, caching, simple-injector, dynacache

I am using [Dynacache](http://dynacache.codeplex.com/) to cache data that will be eventually returned from a service call - to get things working I am just stubbing the data returned.  I am using SimpleInjector for DI and got Dynacache registered with it as pointed out in the answer I got to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261014/registering-dynacaches-with-simpleinjetor)

So I have an integration project within my solution which contains the method I want to cache - which currently looks as below:

```
[CacheableMethod(30)]
public virtual List<MyResponse> GetDataByAccountNumber(int accountNumber)
{
    var response = StubResposne();

    return response;
}
```

With implementation above Dynacache should cache the data for 30 secs and then clear it.  However if I set a breakpoint on the first line in my private StubResponse() method the first time I hit the webpage which uses that data the breakpoint gets hit as expected and the data is returned.  However if I refresh the page straight away again I was expecting that as the data would have been cached (as its within 30 secs) then the breakpoint would not have been hit but it is hit everytime?

Is there something incorrect with how I am using Dynacache?

Comment: Where is your data cached? Is it cached inside the `MemoryCacheService` instance? If this is true, this might be the problem, since according to your previous question you registered it as transient. Perhaps it needs to be a singleton, but do note that this is something that you have to find out from reading the Dynacache docs. Perhaps this type is not thread-safe and you need to have multiple instances.

Comment: hi @Steven - yeah I would expect it to be inside MemoryCacheService - I changed the container.Register from your previous answer to container.RegisterSingle - however I am still seeing the breakpoint getting hit even refreshing the page within 30 secs - unfortunately I dont see much documentation out there for DynaCache? http://dynacache.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Example%20using%20Unity&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For registering with SimpleInjector it should be done as below:

```
container.RegisterSingle<IDynaCacheService>(new MemoryCacheService());
container.Register(typeof(ITestClass), Cacheable.CreateType<TestClass>());
```

Once I done this Caching worked as expected.

Updated with Full test sample Program

```
using System;

namespace DynaCacheSimpleInjector

{
    using System.Threading;


using DynaCache;

using SimpleInjector;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.RegisterSingle<IDynaCacheService>(new MemoryCacheService());
        container.Register(typeof(ITestClass), Cacheable.CreateType<TestClass>());

        var instance = container.GetInstance<ITestClass>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Every 2 seconds the output will change
            Console.WriteLine(instance.GetData(53));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    [CacheableMethod(2)]
    public virtual string GetData(int id)
    {
        return String.Format("{0} - produced at {1}", id, DateTime.Now);
    }
}

public interface ITestClass
{
    string GetData(int id);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add some more information to this answer as I cannot get it to work using just the code you have shown. Each time I request an instance of `ITestClass` and call `GetDataByAccountNumber` it does not return a cached response.

Comment: @qujck - updated with Sample Program - this is working for me

Comment: That's exactly the same as the first test I included in my answer `if I call the method twice from the same instance I get the cached result back second time around`. You're getting one instance from the container and repeatedly calling the same method on the same instance. You don't need to register `IDynaCacheService` as a Singleton to achieve that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to the way you are registering the class that contains the `GetDataByAccountNumber` method.

This first test works - if I call the method twice from the same instance I get the cached result back second time around

```
[Test]
public void GetDataByAccountNumber_CalledTwiceSameInstance_ReturnsCacheSecondTime()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Register<IDynaCacheService>(() => new MemoryCacheService());
    container.Register(typeof(TestClass), Cacheable.CreateType<TestClass>());

    var instance = container.GetInstance<TestClass>();

    instance.GetDataByAccountNumber(1);
    instance.GetDataByAccountNumber(2);

    Assert.That(instance.CallerId == 1);
}
```

If I get 2 different instances from the container then no caching is done

```
public void GetDataByAccountNumber_CalledTwiceDifferentInstance_DoesNotReturnFromCache()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Register<IDynaCacheService>(() => new MemoryCacheService());
    container.Register(typeof(TestClass), Cacheable.CreateType<TestClass>());

    var instance1 = container.GetInstance<TestClass>();

    instance1.GetDataByAccountNumber(1);

    var instance2 = container.GetInstance<TestClass>();

    instance2.GetDataByAccountNumber(2);

    Assert.That(instance2.CallerId == 2);
}
```

The test class looks like this

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int CallerId = 0;

    [CacheableMethod(30)] // TODO - put to 20 minutes and have value in WebConfig as constant
    public virtual List<MyResponse> GetDataByAccountNumber(int callerId)
    {
        CallerId = callerId;

        var response = StubResponse();

        return response;
    }

    // ...
```

---

Simply registering with a lifetime scope does not appear to be compatible with dynacache. In this test method the container returns the same instance for each call within the scope of the lifetime but the results of the method are not cached ....

```
[Test]
public void GetDataByAccountNumber_CalledTwiceLifetimeScopedInstance_ReturnsCacheSecondTime()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Register<IDynaCacheService>(() => new MemoryCacheService());
    container.Register(typeof(TestClass), Cacheable.CreateType<TestClass>(), new LifetimeScopeLifestyle());

    using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var instance1 = container.GetInstance<TestClass>();

        instance1.GetDataByAccountNumber(1);

        var instance2 = container.GetInstance<TestClass>();

        instance2.GetDataByAccountNumber(2);

        // the container does return the same instance
        Assert.That(instance1, Is.EqualTo(instance2));
        // but the caching does not work
        Assert.That(instance2.CallerId, Is.EqualTo(1));
    }
}
```

My advice is that you implement caching with decorators which is real easy with Simple Injector - read the articles of @Steven's starting [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)

Comment: I haven't yet read the full article you have posted yet but are you suggesting get rid of Dynacache and use SimpleInjector to implement caching

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat yes. I assume Dynacache generates some form of dynamic proxy which although cool it will come with extra complexity at some point of time.

Comment: be intersting to see if you could re run your code and see if it functions as expected Registering dynacache as I have shown in my answer?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat I can give it a go and let you know next week. Can you get different instances of `ITestClass` from the `container` and then calling the cached method returns the same cached results?