# Caching data at server layer

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am looking at options for caching data at service layer off my web application (server layer gets data from other systems and at Web Front End I dont want to go on round trip for that data each time - I would like to cache it for say 20 mins and if it is not null load it from cache if not go and retrieve it

I have looked at [Dynacache](http://dynacache.codeplex.com/) which basically looks as if it should do exactly what I want but I have been having problems getting it working with SimpleInjector my DI Framework.  Has anyone used a similar NuGet package or got an example of doing similar?

Comment: You don't indicate what the problems are that you're having. Can you update the question to be more specific?

Comment: @DeanWard - the issue I was seeing with Dynacache - i asked a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283202/dynacache-doesnt-cache-data/24284422?noredirect=1#comment37530001_24284422

Answer (score 0):

I typically set up my web service layer with as little caching as possible, and leave the caching up to the client. If a website needs to only cache a set of data, then that's its own responsibility. If another web application needs real-time access, then I don't want to hinder that.

If I DO need to cache, say a static list that hardly changes, then I typically use something like MemoryCache and set a rolling timeout. For this, I usually write a wrapper for this that utilizes a lambda Func in the .Get() property of my caching service as the source of the cache for that key if the value happens to be null.